# Extend the DHCP lease time by spoofing a device

Tags: windows, networking, network-administration

We have devices that get their IP addresses via DHCP. Those devices are up 24/7 until they have a power loss or restart due to other activities (hardware watchdog etc.)

Unfortunately the devices do not renew the DHCP lease while they are up and running. Therefore it's very likely that the lease expires and they get a different IP address once something unexpected happens (power loss, reboot, ...). This makes it even harder to troubleshoot.

DHCP is managed by our externalized IT department and they are neither happy providing static IP addresses nor configuring DHCP in a way that our devices get the same IP address every time (reservation). It takes weeks until such a request is processed.

So, independent of the fact whether I'll be allowed to use such a tool, I wonder whether it exists:

- spoof a DHCP request for a list of MAC addresses (any common format is ok) so that the lease time will be extended
- no UI interaction required, so I can run it by task scheduler
- for Windows
- price less than 20 €

Technically, it seems that requesting a specific IP is done with DHCP Option 50 (see [RFC 2132, chapter 9.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132#section-9.1)).

Comment: You have a larger issue that a device is not going to solve: the way the people in your organization work together.

Comment: @JanDoggen: that's true. It began with outsourcing of the IT department.

Comment: But that still means that your company gives the instructions to the outsourced entity, doesn't it? Someone in your company fails to order it to do so, i.e. the issue is still within your company.

Comment: I am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for.. On windows systems you can extend the lease by running `ipconfig /renew` will extend the lease. So you could run the command repeatedly after a given interval of time using the Task Scheduler built into windows itself. Have you considered this? Please check if using `ipconfig /renew` extends the lease for your devices.

Comment: @AswinPJ: `ipconfig /renew` works for the machine itself. However, there's no option to pass a MAC address of a different computer, is there? I tried `ipconfig /?` but I could not find an option which would allow that. I can't run that command on the device itself. It's an embedded device.

Comment: is the problem that the IP changes, or that you lose track of the device when it does?  Something that can monitor the DHCP traffic could help, even wireshark with a filter for DHCP, or a DHCP server that logs but doesn't allocate could help with this.  The normal name for a permanent DHCP lease is a reservation.  Can you go over your IT dept's head and force them to give out reservations?

Comment: @Adrien: thanks, I fixed the term. It's more that I lose track of the device when the IP address changes. The device will still work properly, but I will be confused. monitoring the traffic is not so easy. A proxy on my PC is helpful (see also [this question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/27284/9295), but I don't have my PC turned on all time. I could also try to solve it with my [Raspberry WAN emulator](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45043/building-a-wan-emulator), but I don't have so many of them. Sure, it would be best if the IT department could handle such cases.